# ASP.NET core API running in an ARM cluster, does the SDK and docker image matter performance wise?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs

We have an asp.net core API running in AWS ECS (c5.large). Amazon released some containers in the arm that are cheaper and we want to use them (c6g.large) but we have some doubts about ARM.

Currently, our CI/CD pipeline works like this:

1. After a merge in GitHub a webhook fires a pipeline in AWS, that pipelines run in a standard
   5 AWS Image (Linux)
2. In the install phase we install the x86 .NET SDK (Linux) that publishes the API, we have a
   Dockerfile that builds an image using as a base the Microsoft asp.net runtime Linux image, this
   image is added to our internal registry
3. In the deploy phase we take that image from the registry and create a
   The task that is added to ECS.

The questions we have are these:

- Should we use an arm image as the base?
- Should we change the SDK for an arm version? or just adding the -runtime tag is enough? or in the end, it doesn't even matter?

Comment: Can you review https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/arm64-performance-in-net-5

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk shows that the docker image is different for ARM

Comment: I think you will need to use armed image as base as well as the SDK